# Finite Element Library for Heat Transfer 2D

Tags: c++, math, physics, transfer

Hi I am currently COMSOL for calculating the Heat Transfer over time in 2D and I was looking for a library to do it in C++. Is the combination of libMesh and Gmsh the best choice?

It would be really helpful, if you could please also provide an example of such an operation on the suggested library? I use the Fourier equation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that there are a lot of such libraries!

My favorite choice would be Dealii (http://www.dealii.org/) which is very well documented, has a lot of examples and is very flexible. If the 2D heat transfer is only what you need, I think that this is the right library.

Otherwise, you can have a look at Dune (http://www.dune-project.org/dune.html), LibMesh (http://libmesh.sourceforge.net) as you suggested, [GetFem++](http://download.gna.org/getfem/html/homepage/) and so on and so on. There are also a few libraries that allow you to write the weak form of your problem, for example Feel++(http://www.feelpp.org/)  or LifeV ( http://www.lifev.org). (I guess there are others, but these are the ones I know).

Depending on the library, you need an external tool for the mesh and Gmsh is on (good) of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer is there another mesh tool that you would suggest for dealii?
And do you have any examples of 2D thermal transfer?

Comment: I have always used Gmsh, so I can't give many advises for that. DealII provides a list here: http://www.dealii.org/7.2.0/doxygen/deal.II/classGridIn.html. But DealII is already quite good at producing meshes by itself (for simple geometries). By the way, if you need a post-processing software, I strongly advise paraview!

Comment: Perfect! You are very kind! On last thing are there any examples with 2d heat conduction because there are no similar cases in the example steps.

Comment: I would anyway start with the first steps just to get used to DealII. Then, depending on your model, you could start with step 31 and erase what you do not need. Hope it helps!